# How can I create a hook into an external module

Tags: hooks

I want to be able to alter a function inside another module like a hook, but I'm not sure if that's what it's called. I want to alter a function inside another module from my module without changing the external modules code.

This is in version 7.x.

Thanks
Frank N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP offers no mechanism to do that.

If the external function isn't a hook (i.e. it doesn't use `module_invoke()` or `drupal_alter()` to gather data from other modules) then the only thing you can do is patch the function in the external file.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure but I thought I'd ask.